Lost sudo privileges in WSL Ubuntu
I commented out all the sudo privileges in the file sudoers, now I cannot run any command. As I lost sudo privileges I cannot sudoers to re-enable it.
I am using WSL Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64).

Log into root and modify the sudo file. You always have access to root, if you don’t know the password you set, you’ll have to wipe your instant of WSL

Sounds like you did not use visudo to modify /etc/sudoers.
The root user in WSL has no a password. If you login to the root user you can fix things up. Use Cmd or PowerShell and type:
wsl.exe -u root

Now that you are logged in as root, you can run visudo and fix things up.
Logout root by pressing Ctrl-D or typing exit.
Now start WSL as usual. You are back in business!

Thank You. It worked.
